# How to have a 3 column layout with fixed left/right, fluid middle and fixed footer?

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

How can i have a layout similar to this?

I have seen a few solutions that are not quite right for me. Examples and comments I have seen suggest this is not possible. (Diagram is missing overflow auto in the middle).
[image]

For what it is worth: here is my current fiddle (where I decided to trial a table, hrmmmm).

http://jsfiddle.net/valamas/m8R43/6/

**Additional**: 
Printscreen as mentioned in comments. Occurs when dragging/selecting down the page after adding a header. See: http://dabblet.com/gist/3753308
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not too concerned about source order:
http://dabblet.com/gist/3748868

It uses a bit of a hack to get the footer to display on screen on lower viewport heights:

```
body {
    border-bottom: 100px solid; /* height of footer */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

The 'border-box' property is explained here: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/
Basically, what it does is, it makes elements contain borders and paddings inside them. So, the bottom border given to the body here will stay inside the viewport, as opposed to sans-border-box. 
This makes it kind of like a negative space which can be accommodated by the footer. I used 'border' because you may want to tinker with the padding.
As for the footer, it's fixed positioned, so it's relative to the viewport, not the layout which is what you'd get with absolute positioning. Hence it lying on top of the bottom border of the body (which shares its height value).

The center block is fluid because I gave it the 'overflow: hidden' property, which clears floats( http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/ ). It will also work without overflow, but it can cause issues.
Since you want to be able to scroll when the content inside the columns are larger than the content height, I've added a container inside the center column, and gave it overflow: auto.

Comment: It deserves more then +1 but I can only give +1

Comment: this is great, thanks so much for the answer and explanation. It will help as I adjust the interface.

Comment: I was able to add a header panel using the body border hack. Cheers.

Comment: i am having a few problems with adding a 50px header to the page. I have adjusted here: http://dabblet.com/gist/3753308 (changed in CSS marked with my name). It looks great except for when you click and drag the contents top down past the bottom of the browser, the page moves down. Is there a way to prevent that? I have added a screen shot to my post. thank you

Comment: Here you go: http://dabblet.com/gist/3756934. You needed to set border-top instead on the bottom of body to get the header to work like that. Also, there was 'padding-bottom: 0!important' & 'overflow: hidden!important' specified on the body. I removed them since they were unnecessary for the layout. The .center column had a 50px top margin, it is not needed. ...that's about it. If you need to increase/decrease the height of the header/footer, don't forget to adjust the border-width on the body accordingly.

Comment: I used 'px' units for brevity. Please use relative units like 'em' for fixed widths. Here's a tool to convert px to em http://pxtoem.com/. Here's why you should do this: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Answer (score 5):

You can use normal divs.

One wrapper, three inner divs for the left, middle and right. One footer *under* the wrapper div.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="leftSide">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        middle
    </div>
    <div id="rightSide">
        right
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
        footer
    </div>
```

​Then you use the `display: table`; and `table-cell;` on the wrapper and its inner divs:

```
#wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px; /*whatever*/
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#left,
#middle,
#right
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

​Set the widths for the left and right elements and the middle will magically fill up the space.

```
#left
{
    width: 100px;
}

#middle
{
    background: #00f;
}

#right
{
    width: 200px;
}
```

The `display: table;` and `table-cell;` styles mimic the behavior of tables but allow the markup to be semantic elements.

It is supported by all browsers except IE<=7.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/m8R43/9/