# Body with bottom border shows during jquery draggable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jquery-ui draggable. When I drag my box to beyond the bottom of the screen, the body shifts down. How can I prevent this from occurring?

**Tried...**

I have tried making the draggable to be `containment: "*tag*"` where tag is html or body.

Still trying `containment`, I have tried surrounding the layout with a div, however, this breaks the layout scroll-ability of LHS, RHS and center.

The problem is solved by making the `body` - `position: static !important`. This then breaks the layout.

For reference, here is the [jquery-ui draggable page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

**Css Layout**

I have a layout which is header, fixed-height-footer, left and right fixed-width-scrollable, fluid center-scrollable. The header and footer is achievable using a large body border hack. See this question for information on the layout. [How to have a 3 column layout with fixed left/right, fluid middle and fixed footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489909/how-to-have-a-3-column-layout-with-fixed-left-right-fluid-middle-and-fixed-foot)

**Reproduction of the problem.**

Here is my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/valamas/LrXCA/

Please click and drag the blue box below the footer to see a black band or a further pink band.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `scroll: false` to your draggable constructor.

By default the **auto-scroll** option is set to true, if you don't want it, you have to specify `scroll: false` when creating the draggable. See **scroll** option on the [jQuery draggable page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

Working [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LrXCA/13/)