# Responsive 3 column CSS, fixed left and right with fluid center

Tags: css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I am trying to create a 3 column layout where the left and right columns are fixed and the centre is fluid.

I can do this with display table and table cell or I can do it with changing the order of my columns in HTML but both of these complicate my responsive layout - below 1024px column 3 needs to tuck under column 2 with column 1 remaining as is and then under 500px everything goes into one vertical column.

Also each of the columns heights needs to be the height of the highest column as they will have backgrounds.

Lets say I have:

```css
#left {
  width:200px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:red;
  height:100%;
}

#middle {
  margin-left:200px;
}

#right {
  width:200px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:blue;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="left">
    LEFT FIXED
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tristique tellus vel lorem efficitur ornare. Maecenas sit amet commodo velit, at eleifend est. Cras luctus orci vitae erat maximus rutrum. 
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    RIGHT FIXED
  </div>    
</div>
```

How can I make this fixed left, fluid center, fixed right with no display table and not reordering the columns?

The suggested answers use either display table or changing source order both of which I do not want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have a 3 column layout with fixed left/right, fluid middle and fixed footer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489909/how-to-have-a-3-column-layout-with-fixed-left-right-fluid-middle-and-fixed-foot)

Comment: You can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489909/how-to-have-a-3-column-layout-with-fixed-left-right-fluid-middle-and-fixed-foot

Comment: The answers refer to either changing source order or using display table both of which I do not want to use

Comment: My first question is: Why such a complicated layout? Seems like a terrible User Experience?

Comment: How so? There are 3 columns and outer 2 are fixed - as the screen gets smaller then the fluid middle column gets too small to be usable so, initially, I want to move the right column under the middle column giving the middle enough space (it becomes 2 columns then) and then when it gets smaller again all 3 stack into 1 column so they now have full width each?

Answer (score 0):

I added "margin-right:200px;" to your middle id, as the text hid behind.

I then created two Media queries which help to deal with your requests.

CSS:

```
#left {
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: red;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #middle {
        margin-left: 200px;
        margin-right: 200px;
    }

    #right {
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100%;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
        #right {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            top: 300px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #left,
        #middle {
            height: 300px;
            top: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:500px) {
        #left,
        #right,
        #middle {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            height: 100px;
            position: relative;
        }
    }
```